# Issue with position:fixed and hash tags (details in body)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `position:fixed;` navigation bar. Whenever I go to mypage.html#myid, the navigation bar overlaps some of the content of `myid`. How can I move the entire page down a bit so that the navigation bar isn't covering the content?

P.S. I tried `body{padding-top:50px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use margin-top on the myid div? Your main content should be inside a div and this div should be inside the body then myid div can push down from the body to allow enough space for the fixed nav bar.

Some code would help...

Comment: IE7 has issue with margin-top, I think padding-top is much safer.

Comment: IE7 has issues with being a browser.

Comment: How about the good old [`frameset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html)! (just saying, [please don't use it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements) D:)

Comment: Dean_Wilson: margin-top would add unnecessary spacing. I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap without any modifications, which can be found here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit hacky solution needed.

```
#myID:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -285px; /* navigation height */
  height: 285px; /* navigation height */
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

The logic is to add hidden element before the #myID content so browser will give it a hidden space. Giving minus valie as margin-top will prevent it to give phsyical space.

Please have a look at here for detail: http://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

Comment: Could you add a little description in your answer about the links content and a few words on the suggested solution?